# executing a caml query to get a lookup field : "Cannot complete this action.Please try again."?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, visual-studio-2015, caml, lookupfield

It is my caml query code to get the value of a lookup field in SharePoint 2016 on-premises (CSOM).

```
<View>
                                <Query>
                                    <Where>
                                        <Eq>
                                            <FieldRef Name='myLookupField' LookupId='TRUE'/>
                                            <Value Type='Lookup'>18456</Value>
                                        </Eq>
                                    </Where>
                                </Query>
                            </View>
```

tried removing this part "LookupId='TRUE'" but still get this exception:
"Cannot complete this action. Please try again."
I run this caml query in U2U caml query builder but it works.

Comment: check this link https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/119156/caml-query-get-item-by-lookup-value-not-by-id

Comment: @Marwen Jaffel I checked it already but it does not help

Comment: so now visit this https://blog.sharedove.com/adisjugo/index.php/2007/12/12/using-caml-to-query-sharepoint-lists-over-lookup-fields/

Comment: @Marwen Jaffel, sorry but, I checked it already too, but it does not help. thank you

Answer (score 2):

Tested CAML in CSOM like below, it's working:

```
        using (ClientContext ctx=new ClientContext("http://sp/sites/dev/"))
        {
            List list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("MyList22");
            CamlQuery caml = new CamlQuery();
            caml.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='myLookupField' LookupId='TRUE'/><Value Type='Lookup'>1</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";
            ListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(caml);
            ctx.Load(items);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            foreach (ListItem item in items)
            {
                FieldLookupValue value = item["myLookupField"] as FieldLookupValue;
                Console.WriteLine("LookupId: "+ value.LookupId);
                Console.WriteLine("LookupValue: "+ value.LookupValue);

            }
        }
```

This is the test list data:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there any exception in your side ? I tested it without problem in my side.